# How to Redirect error message on index page if user enters wrong ID and Password

Tags: php, html, web

I am new to php i want that if user enter wrong ID and password and error message redirect on index page but i don't know how to do that . I do several things but nothing works.
 I have 2 files called index.php and authenticate.php

> Index.php

```
<form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
            <div class="get_info">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name= "username" id="username" />
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name= "password" />
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onkeypress="submitOnEnter(this, event);" />
        </form>
```

> Authenticate.php

```
 <?php
       include_once('config.php');

    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['password'];

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    $sqll="SELECT * FROM logins where username='$myusername'";
    $resultt=mysql_query($sqll);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultt))
      {
      echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
     //$req=$_request['username'];
      //echo"$req";
      }

    if($count==1){


    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
            session_start(); 
        }

        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;

        header("location: courses/courses.php");
    }
    else {

        header("location: index.php");
        //echo"<script>alert('Username already exist!')</script>";
    //echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: keep in mind that you can't output anything before using a header redirect, and it seems that you echo the username and lastname.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
else{
    // You Can use php headers() instead of a javascript redirect if you want
    print "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='index.php';</script>";
    //echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Does your code redirects if the username and password matches??

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use session

Authenticate.php

```
else {
        $_SESSION['error_message']="Wrong Username or Password";
        header("location: index.php");
    }
```

index.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error_message']){
   echo $_SESSION['error_message'];
   unset($_SESSION['error_message']);
}
```

Comment: where i write this in index.php file? @adnen

Answer (score 0):

> Haven't tested it yet but this should work..

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && $_SESSION['msg'] != ''){
        echo $_SESSION['msg'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']);
    }
    include_once('config.php');
    //You can start the session so long, so you can carry over your error message
    session_start();
    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['username'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['password'];

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    //Get the data
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(!empty($data)){      //Alternatively you could just go "if($result){}"
        //Set the session username (Should use the user id rather or login id | Just tad bit of advice :) )

        $_SESSION['username'] = $data[0]['username'];
        //Set a success message
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You've successfully logged in";
        //Redirect them to their page
        header("location: courses/courses.php");
    }else{
        //Else set message that credentials is bad
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Login credentials bad"
        //Redirect them to the index page
        header("location: index.php");
    }
```

Comment: i cant get any error if i enters wrong information it redirects to the index page but not showing any error msg

Comment: Can i paste how code of index.php?if it is required?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you would echo the $_SESSION['msg'].. But yeah just put the following on the index page:
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && $_SESSION['msg'] != ''){
//Echo the message
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
//Clear it from the session again
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display alert

```
...
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['error_message']){ ?>
       alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['error_message']; ?>");
       <?php unset($_SESSION['error_message']); ?>
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some simple code:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); // Set 401 Error
header("Location: index.php?error=Invalid+Username+or+Password"); // Redirect
exit(); // Don't want php to still keep executing
/* basic script by anonman. in public domain */
?>
```